# Is the REVIT API purely for Addin/plugins to REVIT applications?

Tags: c#, revit-api

What I am trying to do is have a form of options that a user would select from to build out a REVIT Project from a template. Ideally a web page but it could be an application that would live on a person's machine also. Is the REVIT API appropriate for what I am trying to achieve?

I have been trying out the REVIT API, initially I thought with it being an API that the possibility would exist to utilize it via a Web application or a C# program, but what I have been able to find so far is that it is used to only interact with installations of REVIT to create plugins/addins to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Revit API is a pure .NET Windows desktop API for creating add-ins that are loaded by a running session of a Windows desktop Revit installation, cf. the [Revit API developers guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html).